# What does a "Gem of True Sight" do?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

GM awarded us a *gem of true sight* from a module called ["The Priest, The Witch, and the Lost Temple"](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/257361/The-Priest-the-Witch-and-the-Lost-Temple-An-Adventure). However, the DM said the adventure did not provide a description for the item so we are not sure what it is or what it does.

What is the description for this magic item?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Could it be referring to a [gem of seeing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items?filter-type=0&filter-search=seeing&filter-requires-attunement=&filter-effect-type=&filter-effect-subtype=&filter-has-charges=)?

The [gem of seeing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items?filter-type=0&filter-search=seeing&filter-requires-attunement=&filter-effect-type=&filter-effect-subtype=&filter-has-charges=) does grant true sight.

According to the [module's description and item list](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/258072/Magic-Items-from-The-Priest-the-Witch-and-the-Lost-Temple?src=by_author_of_product)

> "In my adventure The Priest, the Witch, and the Lost Temple, two new
>   magic items are featured: the Gem of Interdimensionality and the Orb
>   of Undeath."

Gem of Seeing has been around for decades in various editions, and people have been mistakenly referring to it as Gem of True Sight for a long time, to the point where Defense of the Ancients made a similar item to gem of seeing and called it "Gem of True Sight". The more I research, the more it seems to be a very pervasive mistake, the DND equivalent of Nukular vs Nuclear.

Comment: Miles, that is possible, I have found a blog (credit V2Blast) that the author sometimes responds to. I have asked him and will update you if I hear back from him.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm almost sure that particular item was called a "gem of true seeing" or "gem of true sight" in previous editions.  So it may just be one of those "oops 3rd edition momentarily took over my brain" kind of things.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym In the other answer, Zanikster found that the Gem of Seeing dates back to the 90s. I think it's just that everyone just refers to the gem of seeing as the gem of true sight, and has for a very long time.